# KendoUI Drop Down List Data Source Add Item Error

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, kendo-ui, sharepoint-2013

I am using JQuery to add KendoUI.DropDown Box. It binds fine with a data source and displays results as expected. But when I try to add a custom item to the data source:

```
// create a new data item
dsBusinessUnit.add( { Value: "All Business Units" });
```

It gives the following error:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property '__count' of undefined or null reference
```

I'm binding the data source as follows, and it works fine as long as I don't add an extra item.

```
// business unit data source
var dsBusinessUnit = new kendo.data.DataSource({ 
    type: "odata",                   
    transport: {        
        read: 
        {
            url: "http://sharepointservername/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/dropdownfieldfunction",
            dataType: "json"
        }
    },
    schema: {       
        model: {
            fields: {
                Value: { type: "string" }
            }
        }
    },
    serverFiltering: true,
    serverSorting: true
});
```

What is that I am doing wrong. I've seen examples on Telerik's website and they have provided the same syntax. I've tried including all .js files, but it doesn't seem to work. Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: http://sharepointservername/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/dropdownfieldfunction is not working in browser. Make sure your `datasource url` is working and returning `json` object.

Comment: You are adding data to a DataSource but your DataSource does not include a `create` method. KendoUI thinks that you want to add it to the server not just to the local copy.

Answer (score 2):

I see no problem to add new item to the dataSource. Basically here is an example from the demos

```
  $("#products").kendoDropDownList({
                    dataTextField: "ProductName",
                    dataValueField: "ProductID",
                    dataSource: {
                        transport: {
                            read: {
                                dataType: "jsonp",
                                url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Products",
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

          $("#btn").click(function(){
            $("#products").getKendoDropDownList().dataSource.insert({
            ProductName: "Foo",
             ProductId: 22
            })
          })
```

[Here is a running example](http://jsbin.com/gera/2/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to make any CRUD(Create, Read, Update or Delete operation) for the kendo UI Objects , then you have to define this procedure in the kendo ui ajax call.

Define the method for the create and after that may be you are able to add the custom data to the dropdown